# How can I get Certbot to run after unresponsive login session?

Tags: certbot, ipc, lockfile

A login session (under Jessie) running `certbot -d example.com -d www.example.com` froze, and when I tried to run Let's Encrypt's certbot from another session, it said, "Another instance of Certbot is already running." I did a `kill -HUP` on the still-running process, and tried to run certbot with a `--config-dir` argument among other things, and got the same error.

How can I ask for the first attempt to be forgotten?

Is there a lockfile I can delete?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a related post on the let's encrypt community site:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solved-another-instance-of-certbot-is-already-running/44690

To restate the possible soultion:
ps -ef | grep certb
to find the PID, then
kill it.

If it is not running, try to find `.certbot.lock` files, and delete them.

Comment: I had already done a `kill -HUP` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sending SIGHUP is often not enough. Kill means at least SIGTERM.